# If X is Geometric(p), show that $\displaystyle E\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right]=\log\left( (1-p)^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\right)$

Tags: probability, statistics

If X is Geometric(p), show that $\displaystyle E\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right]=\log\left( (1-p)^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\right)$

I found that $E\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right]=\log p^{\frac{p}{p-1}}$ instead using Taylor expansion of $log(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$.

$$E\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right]=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+X}p(1-p)^x=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{y}p(1-p)^{y-1}=-\frac{p}{p-1}\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-p)^y}{y}$$ and since $-\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-p)^y}{y}=log(1-(1-p))=\log(p)$, then we get

$$=\frac{p}{p-1}\log p$$

Did I go wrong somewhere with the $1-p$?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the argument, the answer seems to be $\log(p^{\frac p{p-1}})$...

Comment: Thanks for looking over it, perhaps it was a typo.

Comment: Go through the details again slowly, I think you'll figure out it was a typo on your own. The best way to make sure you're right is to not take anything for granted and try to think "why is this equal to that" at each step. That's a tip you can use everywhere in mathematics, and skipping this step is the main source of errors in general. ;)

Comment: that's very helpful advice! not to mention it builds confidence.

Comment: Yes, I would pay to see the day where there would be one course with no exams and JUST that ; people trying to fix their own problems. But hey, I'm a dreamer.